# how do i make an appointment record in java?

Tags: java

Ok so basically i have to make an appointment record of doctors and patients. I have already made records of doctors and patients but now i have to make an appointment record in which i have to assign one patient to  a doctor based on the patient's illness and the doctor's specialization. I am new to java so i am not so good at it so if you can help me out, i will highly appreciate that :-) i will show u the coding i did so far. It contains some extra stuff in it as well but i have to add it in it for my assignment. And yea, the names i gave to some variables and objects are sort of weird but that is cos java wont let me give them a proper and appropriate name.. Anyways here is my coding :-

```
package samplee.java;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class patient$ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<patientss> patient1= new ArrayList<patientss>();
        ArrayList<doctorss> doctor1= new ArrayList<doctorss>();
        Scanner src= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner stc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sdc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner update= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ill=new Scanner(System.in);
        int id,it,num,i,docid,docit,docnum,docid1;
        String name,docname,docspecial,illness;
        int ages,docage;
        int id1;
        Boolean leave = false;
        while(!leave){
            patientss xx= new patientss();
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's ID ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            id=src.nextInt();
            if(id != -1){
            xx.setId(id);

        } 
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's name ");
        System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
        name=stc.next();
        if(id != -1){
            xx.setName(name);
            patient1.add(xx);
        } 
        System.out.println("Enter the patient's phone number");
        System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
        num=sdc.nextInt();
        if(id != -1){
            xx.setNum(num);
            patient1.add(xx);
        } 
        System.out.println("Enter the type of illness the patient has");
        System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
        illness=ill.next();
        if(id!= -1){
            xx.setIllness(illness);
            patient1.add(xx);
        }

            else { leave = true; }//Escape the while loop.
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a patient");
        it=sc.nextInt();
        patientss tt= new patientss();
        for(i=0;i<patient1.size();i++)
            {
            tt=patient1.get(i);
            if(it==tt.getId()) 
            System.out.println(tt.toString());
            break;
            }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of the patient you want to update");
        Scanner id11= new Scanner(System.in);
        id1=id11.nextInt();
        int up,id2;
        String namess;
        int phones;
        patientss dd= new patientss();
        for(i=0;i<patient1.size();i++){
            dd=patient1.get(i);
            if(id1==dd.getId()){
                System.out.println("If you want to change the name, type 2");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the number, type 3");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the id, type 1");
                up=update.nextInt();
                if(up==1){
                    System.out.println("Enter a new ID ");
                    Scanner idd= new Scanner(System.in);
                    id2=idd.nextInt();
                    dd.setId(id2);
                    patient1.add(dd);

            }
                else if(up==2){
                    System.out.println("Enter a new name");
                    Scanner namme=new Scanner(System.in);
                    namess=namme.next();
                    dd.setName(namess);
                    patient1.add(dd);

                }
                else if(up==3){
                    System.out.println("Enter a new phone");
                    Scanner newphone= new Scanner(System.in);
                    phones=newphone.nextInt();
                    dd.setNum(phones);
                    patient1.add(dd);

                }
        }
            System.out.println(dd);
            break;
        } 
        boolean over = false;
        while(!over){
            doctorss xt= new doctorss();
            System.out.println("Enter the doctor's ID ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            docid=src.nextInt();
            if(docid != -1){
            xt.setDocid(docid);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the doctor's name ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            docname=stc.next();
            if(docid != -1){
                xt.setDocname(docname);
                doctor1.add(xt);
            } 
            System.out.println("Enter the doctor's phone number");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            docnum=sdc.nextInt();
            if(docid != -1){
                xt.setDocnum(docnum);
                doctor1.add(xt);
            }
            System.out.println("What does the doctor specialize in?");
            String specialize;
            Scanner special= new Scanner(System.in);
            specialize=special.next();
            if(docid != -1){
                xt.setSpecialize(specialize);
                doctor1.add(xt);
            }
                else { over = true; }//Escape the while loop.
            }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a doctor");
        docit=sc.nextInt();
        doctorss tti= new doctorss();
        for(i=0;i<doctor1.size();i++){
            tti=doctor1.get(i);
            if(docit==tti.getDocid()) 
            System.out.println(tti.toString());
            }

        } 
    }
```

and these r my classes..

```
package samplee.java;

public class patientss {
int id;
String name;
int num;
String illness;
public String getIllness() {
    return illness;
}

public void setIllness(String illness) {
    this.illness = illness;
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String toString(){
    return name+" "+id+" "+num+ " "+illness;
}
}
```

and here is my doctor's class:-

```
package samplee.java;

public class doctorss {
int docid;
String specialize;
public String getSpecialize() {
    return specialize;
}
public void setSpecialize(String specialize) {
    this.specialize = specialize;
}
public int getDocid() {
    return docid;
}
public void setDocid(int docid) {
    this.docid = docid;
}
public String getDocname() {
    return docname;
}
public void setDocname(String docname) {
    this.docname = docname;
}
public int getDocnum() {
    return docnum;
}
public void setDocnum(int docnum) {
    this.docnum = docnum;
}
String docname;
int docnum;
public String toString(){
    return docname+" "+docid+" and "+docnum+" he specializes in"+specialize;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I want to make some comments regarding your code:

1. Follow Oracle convention and name classes in camel-case starting
   with capital letter.
2. Class name must not be plural: not `Doctors` but `Doctor`. In your case it describes single entity, not a group of doctors or something.
3. Not necessary to name fields like `docid`, `id` is enough as it's defined in `Doctor` class.
4. Illness in my opinion must be separated class. Unfortunately, a patient can be ill more than once with different illnesses.

I would propose you the following classes(the details like getters-setters are omitted, but I hope you will get the idea):

```
class Doctor {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

class Patient {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

class Illness {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

class Appointment {
    private Doctor doctor;
    private Patient patient;
    private Illness illness;
    private Date date;

    public Appointment(
      Doctor doctor, Patient patient, Illness illness, Date date
    ) {
       this.doctor = doctor;
       this.patient = patient;
       this.illness = illness;
       this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Edit:
When user inputs doctors and patients you have to "remember" them somehow. Use, for example, array or `ArrayList` for that:

```
ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
// read the patient here
patients.add(patient)
```

So, in the step where you need to make an appointment you will have to ask user to input: doctor id, patient id, illness id and desired date. Then you have to find doctor, patient and illness in "remembered" lists:

```
Patient patient
for (Patient item : patients) {
    if (item.getId() == idFromUser) {
        patient = item
    }
}
if (patient == null) {
    System.out.println("Patient not found. Choose another ID.");
   // here you have to force user to re-input the value.
}
```

Then just create new appointment:

```
new Appointment(doctor, patient, illness, date);
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks but how do i assign the patients and doctors together :/ that's confusing me a lot :-/

Comment: I've also added examples how to put patient into list and how to search. The same you can do with doctors and illnesses. The code is rather pseudocode just to show the idea.

Comment: thanks..though I do have one question.. Although it helps bring all of needed data into one class and now i can use the If statement to assign the doctors and patients together according to the patient's illness but do u think instead of letting the patient write the type of illness he has, i can just provide him a list of some of the illness that he is likely to have and the ones that the hospital has the doctors for? Cos if i use String to input the type of illness, the program may not be able to assign that patient to the required doctor due to some likely capital or small letter issues.

Comment: I do not know the real goal of this task. If you want it to be really interesting you can even do the following: introduce class Specialisation which has two fields `doctor` and `illness`. Then you can prepare list of doctors, list of illnesses and list of specialisations(specialisation means illness which doctor can treat). Then you ask user something like: press [1] if you have flu, press [2] if you have diarrhea etc. User presses key and you find illness by id(1 and 2 are illness ids). Than you can ask him to select doctor(you may have several doctors for flu): [1] Dr. Dre [2] Dr. Alban etc

Comment: Dr. Dre? haha nice xD.. Hmm thanks yea that's what i think i should do. Like I can show the user the list of some of the  illness and he can just pick one of them for example if he has any form of allergy i can just simply assign him to an Allergist in the hospital.. And if we don't have the doctors for the treatment of his illness, i can just display to him a message on the screen saying go to another hospital lol.. Is that a good idea? I mean.. I am sure not all the hospitals have doctors of all the specialization..

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a bro but just a simple note, you don't have to create more objects of Scanner one is enough.
I usually go with
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
then just use it whenever you need, like:
int x = input.nextInt();
String s = input.next();
etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).